# Hand-drawn curve generator between two points

Tags: curve-fitting, turtle-graphics, bezier

I am trying to draw a curve between two points in such a way that it looks something like a hand drawn curve. How do I do this? My preliminary thinking is to (a) come up with a set of at least another two points and (b) then do a Bezier Curve for those points. Is this the right track? Is there any work already done on similar topic that I can refer?

I am doing this in Python using Turtle graphics, but the main question is about the algorithm, not the implementation in python, even though a native python implementation would be the best.

Comment: What does "a hand drawn curve between two points" mean?

Comment: @fang: Please draw two points using a pen by your own hand and join them using the same pen by your own hand without using any other instrument (such as, and including a ruler). This is a hand-drawn line.  -1 for asking obvious question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try logointerpreter.com, it has the Bezier Curve already implemented:

http://www.logointerpreter.com/logo-reference/img/ref_4.jpg

See reference here:
http://www.logointerpreter.com/logo-reference/turtle-graphics-curved-paths.php

Best regards,

Comment: Thanks very much. Since posting the question, I thought some more and came up with my own algorithm, which is very similar to what you pointed to. I selected two points in between the  given points at random and then created a Bezier with the random points as the CPs. I am starting to think the choice of the CPs will determine how 'natural' the curve looks. I will post the code after some more experiments.